# High ping on every IP address, on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, macbook, ping, macbook-pro

I’ve some weird problem. I’m using Wi-Fi on my MacBook Pro. There is some network issue. If I ping some random server, no matter what server it will be, response is taking too much time repeatedly. Example, result of ping of `google.com`

```
PING google.com (62.212.33.173): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=0 ttl=59 time=2.430 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=23.083 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=3.233 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=3.279 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=10.242 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=5 ttl=59 time=121.946 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=6 ttl=59 time=273.628 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=7 ttl=59 time=751.125 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=8 ttl=59 time=629.884 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=9 ttl=59 time=2.645 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=10 ttl=59 time=5.373 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=11 ttl=59 time=5.376 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=12 ttl=59 time=3.530 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=13 ttl=59 time=2.929 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=14 ttl=59 time=3.461 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=15 ttl=59 time=218.565 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=16 ttl=59 time=373.489 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=17 ttl=59 time=110.334 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=18 ttl=59 time=592.598 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=19 ttl=59 time=2.430 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=20 ttl=59 time=4.042 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=21 ttl=59 time=2.996 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=22 ttl=59 time=6.649 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=23 ttl=59 time=9.892 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=24 ttl=59 time=3.224 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=25 ttl=59 time=309.118 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=26 ttl=59 time=470.419 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=27 ttl=59 time=204.494 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=28 ttl=59 time=679.906 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=29 ttl=59 time=2.046 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=30 ttl=59 time=13.657 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.33.173: icmp_seq=31 ttl=59 time=2.358 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
32 packets transmitted, 32 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.046/151.512/751.125/229.727 ms
```

My network connection isn't that bad, but on some servers (ex: 104.160.141.3), response takes more than 2000ms sometimes.

```
PING 104.160.141.3 (104.160.141.3): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=1329.467 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=462.116 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=79.538 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=104.068 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=82.296 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=80.556 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=86.953 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=81.422 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=1134.962 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=9 ttl=56 time=871.276 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=10 ttl=56 time=1349.927 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=11 ttl=56 time=485.434 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=12 ttl=56 time=83.883 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=13 ttl=56 time=78.866 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=14 ttl=56 time=79.491 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=15 ttl=56 time=78.346 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=16 ttl=56 time=78.318 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=17 ttl=56 time=80.434 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 19
Request timeout for icmp_seq 20
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=20 ttl=56 time=1704.739 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=21 ttl=56 time=702.861 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=22 ttl=56 time=84.213 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=23 ttl=56 time=124.218 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=24 ttl=56 time=83.136 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=25 ttl=56 time=80.534 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=26 ttl=56 time=90.792 ms
64 bytes from 104.160.141.3: icmp_seq=27 ttl=56 time=97.689 ms
^C
--- 104.160.141.3 ping statistics ---
29 packets transmitted, 26 packets received, 10.3% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 78.318/369.059/1704.739/483.644 ms
```

What can the problem be? and how to fix it?

Comment: If it's wireless could be any kind of interference.

Comment: I think some app of mac is sending analyses or diagnoses. Is there any way to catch this requests?

Comment: You'd probably be better pinging your router's IP address if possible to eliminate the internet side of things. Is it a new laptop or is it a problem that has just appeared on an existing laptop?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that there are tools in place on the intermediary servers that are slowing down this particular type of traffic to prevent, or at least make it difficult to perform a DDOS attack.